# Compilation omits code after fixed blocks in certain methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, il

We have the following method in a class in one of our projects:

```cs
private unsafe void SomeMethod()
{
    // Beginning of the method omitted for brevity

    var nv = new Vector4[x];

    fixed (Vector4* vp = nv)
    {
        fixed (float* tp = /* Source float ptr */)
        {
            fixed (double* ap = /* Source double ptr */)
            {
                for (var i = atlArray.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
                {
                    vp[((i + 1) << 3) - 2] = new Vector4(tp[i], btt, 0.0f, 1.0f);
                    // Additional Vector4 construction omitted for brevity

                    nttp[i] = new Vector2(tp[i], this.ttvp);
                    nts[i] = string.Format(ap[i], /* etc. */);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    this.ts = nts;
    this.ttp = nttp;
    this.V = nv; // <- This is a property setter
}
```

I've had to obfuscate this, but hopefully it's still clear enough to get an idea of what's going on.

On one of our developers' machines, in debug builds, the C# compiler removes the three assignments that occur after the `fixed` block is closed. If we attempt to put a breakpoint on these lines, the breakpoint skips to the ending brace of the method when the application starts. Code that appears between a `fixed` block and the end of a method is removed in other methods too, but puzzlingly, not in all of them.

After some experimentation, we found that turning *on* optimization for the affected project caused the missing code to be included. However, this work-around fails for our unit testing - the code is missing, and changing the optimization of the affected project and its test project does not help. We also found that moving the three assignments inside the inner-most `fixed` statement worked - it becomes clear why when examining the IL.

In the debug DLL built on the affected machine (with optimization turned off), a return op appears directly after `ap` is popped off the stack:

```
IL_03a1:  nop
IL_03a2:  ldc.i4.0
IL_03a3:  conv.u
IL_03a4:  stloc.s    ap
IL_03a6:  ret
```

This explains why moving the three assignments before the `stloc` instruction works. In the debug DLL built on my machine, the return op occurs in the expected place, after the three assignments:

```
IL_03a5:  nop
IL_03a6:  ldc.i4.0
IL_03a7:  conv.u
IL_03a8:  stloc.s    ap
IL_03aa:  nop
IL_03ab:  ldc.i4.0
IL_03ac:  conv.u
IL_03ad:  stloc.s    tp
IL_03af:  nop
IL_03b0:  ldc.i4.0
IL_03b1:  conv.u
IL_03b2:  stloc.s    vp
IL_03b4:  ldarg.0
IL_03b5:  ldloc.s    nts
IL_03b7:  stfld      string[] N.B.E.B::ts
IL_03bc:  ldarg.0
IL_03bd:  ldloc.s    nttp
IL_03bf:  stfld      valuetype [SharpDX]SharpDX.Vector2[] N.B.E.B::ttp
IL_03c4:  ldarg.0
IL_03c5:  ldloc.s    nv
IL_03c7:  call       instance void N.B.E.B::set_V(valuetype [SharpDX]SharpDX.Vector4[])
IL_03cc:  nop
IL_03cd:  ret
```

We've so far failed to produce an SSCCE - this seems to manifest only in very specific circumstances, and only in one of our projects. We've checked that the same versions of Visual Studio, the .NET framework, the C# compiler and MSBuild are being used on both machines. We've checked other potential differences like OS version and updates. Things appear to be the same on both machines (they are the same model of laptop). We're a bit puzzled, frankly. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague, the developer whose machine this was affecting, found a difference in the diagnostic output from the build - it was the C# compiler. We thought that MSBuild was using the csc.exe in the expected location (*c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin*), but bizarrely, it was actually executing a csc.exe in *C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Extensions*, which had a completely different version. We don't know how that compiler executable came to be there, or how it was being referenced by MSBuild, but once it was removed, MSBuild reverted to using the version of csc.exe in its home Bin directory, and the code is being built correctly now.

Comment: Isn't that the Roslyn compiler? I have that in C:\Users\Svick\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Extensions\2wcdsxyh.slm\rcsc.exe. If that is the case, you might want to [report this bug to the Roslyn team](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create).

Comment: @svick That's an interesting lead - I'll find out from my colleague on Monday if he ever installed the Roslyn compiler, and report this issue to the Roslyn team if he did. I'll report back.